# Comando para exclusão de duplicatas query

Tags: sql, query, microsoft-excel, excel-vba, macro

Tenho duas bases de dados:

A - x; y; z

B - x; y; z; w; l;

Preciso que a query exclua as informações duplicadas da base B, quando ela for adicionada junto a base A, de forma automática. Ou seja, ao linkar as duas bases eu preciso que a query me devolva: x;y;z;w;l e não x;y;z;x;y;z;w;l.

Comment: Como você tentou?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Olá,
é mais indicado você utilizar o Left Join ao juntar as duas bases e após realizar a mesclagem, escolha as colunas que deseja mostrar na sua consulta.

No caso, você iria escolher as colunas w;l

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).